# Is there a nicer way of building an OracleCommand?

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle, odp.net

I'm making an ODP.NET database application for my school project using wpf. I have a list of checkboxes corresponding to table's columns. Is there a nicer way of building a select statement than just going through a foreach loop?

I've looked into OracleCommandBuilder Class but it didn't seem to have what i was looking for.

```
private IEnumerable<CheckBox> allC = employeesC = Employees.Children.OfType<CheckBox>();
string selectStatement = "SELECT ";

foreach (CheckBox cb in allC)
{
  if (cb.IsChecked ?? false)
  {
    selectStatement += cb.Content + ", ";
  }
}
```

Comment: You may be interested in [SqlKata](https://sqlkata.com/), a library for building SQL statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but you should be able to do some linq fanciness with that loop and if condition:

```
string selectStatement = "SELECT " + string.Join(", ", allC
    .Where(c => c.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault())
    .Select(c => c.Content));
```